# im getting an error on my program

Tags: java, swing, class, actionlistener

```
import java.awt.*; //Container, GridLayout, *, or etc...
import javax.swing.*; //JFrame, JLabel, *, or etc...
import java.awt.event.*;
public class NumerologyEC extends JFrame
{
    private static final int Width = 400;
    private static final int Height = 100;

    private JLabel wordJL;
    private JTextField wordTF;

    private JButton calculateJB, exitJB;

    private CalculateButtonHandler cbHandler;
    private ExitButtonHandler ebHandler;

   public  NumerologyEC()
   {
       setTitle ("Numerology Extra Credit");
       wordJL = new JLabel ("Enter a word: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);

       wordTF = new JTextField(10);

       calculateJB = new JButton ("Calculate");
       cbHandler = new CalculateButtonHandler();
       calculateJB.addActionListener (cbHandler);

       exitJB = new JButton ("Exit");
       ebHandler = new ExitButtonHandler();
       exitJB.addActionListener (ebHandler);

       Container pane = getContentPane();
       pane.setLayout (new GridLayout (2, 2));

       pane.add(wordJL);
       pane.add(wordTF);
       pane.add(calculateJB);
       pane.add(exitJB);

       setSize(Width, Height);
       setVisible (true);
       setDefaultCloseOperation (EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

      private class CalculateButtonHandler  implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionListener e)
        {
            String word;

            word = String.parseString (wordTF.getText());
        }
    }

    private class ExitButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerfromed (ActionEvent e)
        {
          System.exit (0);  
        }
    }

   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
    NumerologyEC rectObject = new NumerologyEC();
    }


}
```

i keep getting an error on the "private class CalculateButtonHandler implemets ACtionListener"

What am i missing?

Comment: `public void actionPerformed (ActionListener e)` should be `public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)`. Also, check your z-key, it seems broken.

Comment: Also, "actionPerformed" isn't spelled correctly in the ExitButtonHandler class.

Answer (score 1):

be  careful,the Method in  `ExitButtonHandler`  is  wrong:

```
public void actionPerfromed (ActionEvent e)
{
  System.exit (0);  
}
```

The correct spelling is:

```
actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
  System.exit(0);
}
```

second: the  method  in the CalculateButtonHandler is  wrong,the  right method is

```
public void actionPerfromed (ActionEvent e)
{

}
```

not

```
public void actionPerfromed (ActionListener e)
{

}
```

also the code

```
word = String.parseString (wordTF.getText());
```

is  wrong, `String` class  doesn't  have  the `parseString()` method. I think you want  have get the  input  from  the input  TextArea  and  cast  it  to  String, why not have the `word=wordTF.getText()`, because the `wordTF.getText()` is a String.